# Deleting all rows until certain value - than do the same for the next group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset about the returns of stocks in the last 30 years. Now I need to delete all rows(years) for a company until the first row, which isn´t NA. But I need to leave all other rows with NA for that company, that may occur later. Then the code should jump to the next company(Id) and restart the process.

I already tried the following code, but to be honest I´m kind of lost.

```
cleaning <- function (DT, colnames){
  for(cols in colnames) 
    if(is.na(cols)){
      DT[, cols := NULL]
    } else {
      break
    }
}
MergedDT[, cleaning(MergedDT, RET), by = "Id"]
```

I received the following warning for that code:

> ```
> > 1: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(cols, NULL)) :   Adding new column
> > 'cols' then assigning NULL (deleting it).
> ```

Furthermore, I think that there is a way more efficient way to solve that problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `group_by`, to do the analysis per company (or per `cyl` in this example) and `do` to find the first instance in which years (or `mpg`) is not NA should work:

```
df <- structure(list(model = c("Datsun 710", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", 
"Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", "Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", 
"Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", "Lotus Europa", "Volvo 142E", "Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Valiant", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", 
"Ferrari Dino", "Hornet Sportabout", "Duster 360", "Merc 450SE", 
"Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Lincoln Continental", 
"Chrysler Imperial", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28", 
"Pontiac Firebird", "Ford Pantera L", "Maserati Bora"), mpg = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 33.9, 21.5, NA, 26, 30.4, 21.4, NA, NA, NA, 18.1, 
19.2, 17.8, 19.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 15.5, 
15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 15.8, 15), cyl = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8), disp = c(108, 146.7, 140.8, 78.7, 75.7, 71.1, 120.1, 
79, 120.3, 95.1, 121, 160, 160, 258, 225, 167.6, 167.6, 145, 
360, 360, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472, 460, 440, 318, 304, 350, 
400, 351, 301), hp = c(93, 62, 95, 66, 52, 65, 97, 66, 91, 113, 
109, 110, 110, 110, 105, 123, 123, 175, 175, 245, 180, 180, 180, 
205, 215, 230, 150, 150, 245, 175, 264, 335), drat = c(3.85, 
3.69, 3.92, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.11, 3.9, 
3.9, 3.08, 2.76, 3.92, 3.92, 3.62, 3.15, 3.21, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 
2.93, 3, 3.23, 2.76, 3.15, 3.73, 3.08, 4.22, 3.54), wt = c(2.32, 
3.19, 3.15, 2.2, 1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 1.935, 2.14, 1.513, 2.78, 
2.62, 2.875, 3.215, 3.46, 3.44, 3.44, 2.77, 3.44, 3.57, 4.07, 
3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 3.52, 3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 3.17, 
3.57), qsec = c(18.61, 20, 22.9, 19.47, 18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 18.9, 
16.7, 16.9, 18.6, 16.46, 17.02, 19.44, 20.22, 18.3, 18.9, 15.5, 
17.02, 15.84, 17.4, 17.6, 18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 16.87, 17.3, 
15.41, 17.05, 14.5, 14.6), vs = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), am = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), gear = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5), carb = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(
    .[first(which(!is.na(.$mpg))):nrow(.),]
  )
```

Comment: First all of thank you for the quick response. But I tried running your code and it deleted all the rows with an NA value in the mpg col.

Comment: That was only because I didn't add any NAs after the first non-na entry. I've updated my sample data (you should supply some sample data, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8675075)

Answer (score 0):

Iiuc, you are looking to trim beginning NA returns for each ID, here is an option:

```
DT[-DT[,.I[seq_len(match(TRUE, !is.na(RET)) - 1L)], .(ID)]$V1]
```

output:

```
   ID  RET
1:  1 0.02
2:  1   NA
3:  2 0.01
4:  2   NA
5:  3 0.01
6:  3 0.05
7:  3 0.02
```

data:

```
DT <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3), RET=c(NA,0.02,NA, NA,NA,0.01,NA, 0.01,0.05,0.02))
```

`DT`:

```
    ID  RET
 1:  1   NA
 2:  1 0.02
 3:  1   NA
 4:  2   NA
 5:  2   NA
 6:  2 0.01
 7:  2   NA
 8:  3 0.01
 9:  3 0.05
10:  3 0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DT[DT[,  .I[cumsum(!is.na(RET)) > 0], ID]$V1]

   ID  RET
1:  1 0.02
2:  1   NA
3:  2 0.01
4:  2   NA
5:  3 0.01
6:  3 0.05
7:  3 0.02
```

Data (stolen from chinsoon12 (**O**riginal question **p**oster failed to provide reproducible data)):

```
DT <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3), RET=c(NA,0.02,NA, NA,NA,0.01,NA, 0.01,0.05,0.02))
```